# calculating percentage of a value in an oracle database

Tags: database, oracle

I'd like to do some statistics on a row in a oracle table.

```
select totaltime from server_metrics;
```

gives me a list of numeric values.
What I now want is to know is how many percentage of the values in the table are higher than 100?

I can easily do via two queries and calculate my self:

```
select count(*) from server_metrics;
select count(*) from server_metrics where totaltime > 100;
```

But is it possible to do this via one query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select 100
         * sum(case when totaltime > 100 then 1 else 0 end)
         / Nullif(count(*),0)
from server_metrics;
```

Comment: `Nullif(count(*),0) = NULL` , if `COUNT(*) = 0`. You intent for `NVL()` ?

Comment: To avoid a division-by-zero error on an empty table by treating a value of count(\*) of zero as Null. Count(\*) is never null, of course.